# How to create branches structure through Powershell

Tags: git, powershell, github

I've installed git for powershell. And I work with git a lot. I do some "push" and "commit" commands.
However, I had only one branch and now is time to add some more branches (dev, staging, production or master).

I found on help page (git help) 'git branches' command where says - branch     List, create, or delete branches

But apparently I don't know how to create all of these branches.
I would like to have one script for more serious source control, as I mentioned multiple branches, for testers, developers and etc.

Any help would be appreciated

UPDATE: I found commands, but I dunno what to choose.[image]

Comment: First find the commit that you want to be the new branch's head. Then run `git branch <new_branch_name> <head_commit>` to create the new branch. See more in `git branch --help`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For creating a new branch, based on master, for new work to go into:

```
$ git checkout -b amend-my-name
Switched to a new branch 'amend-my-name'
```

`git checkout` is a command you’ll use a lot, to switch between branches. The `-b flag` tells it to create a new branch at the same time. By default, the new branch is based upon whatever branch you were on.

You can also choose what to base the new branch on. A quite common thing to do is, just for example:

```
git checkout -b new-branch existing-branch
```

This creates a new branch `new-branch`, based on `existing-branch`.

Moreover you can find a best practice for branching [here](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)

Answer (score 3):

You can make branch from current head by `git checkout -b dev`.

`-b dev` option means that making branch dev and checking out 'dev' branch.

Comment: Thanks. I just found it. Could you direct me to some link where I can read about setting up github development environment? Like three branches (dev, staging, production) with some push request?

Comment: @Stefan0309 https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow
This is what you want.